# How do I convert time in excel from 2017-04-03T12:16:27.961Z format to a DD-MMM-YY format

Tags: excel-formula

How do  I convert time in excel  from 2017-04-03T12:16:27.961Z format to a DD-MMM-YY format

I am trying to convert data from CA Agile into excel so that i can depict changes over time.  Right now I am forced to manually change the format instead of using an automated way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula, then format as you wish:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"Z","")
```

[image]

Comment: wont that depend on regional settings?

Comment: No. As the date is YYYY-MM-DD. it is universally accepted.

Comment: Sweet!  I will have to try to remember that universality.  I personally set my regional setting to yy/mm/dd.  CLOSE but no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula and format the cell with `dd-mmm-yy` ,

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(LEFT(A1,10),"dd-mmm-yy"))
```

[image]